# Can you make Excel formula's iterate and count loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-formula

I'm almost certain the answer is 'no', but I thought I'd ask the people here just in case there is some magic formula I haven't yet found...

So lets say I have a table of values;

I've also got another cell somewhere (lets just say that this cell is A1 for my example), which has another number in it.  This number is actually a percentage (lets call it 20% in this example)

So I have a table that looks like this

```
      A     B     C     D     E
1 |  20
2 |
3 | Number
4 |  23
5 |  68
6 | 145
7 |   8
```

The simplest way to explain it is to say I'm going to reduce each number by the percentage given in cell A1 (20% in my example).  I'm then going to repeat (so reduce the new values by another 20%) until the answer is zero (rounded to 2dp in this example, though I may need more or less rounding later).
I'm trying to work out how many times the formula must run to get the values to 0

Like I said, I'm almost certain this cannot be done outside of scripting (VBA etc.), since to my knowledge excel formulas can't loop and count??

I'm also sure that this is actually quite an easy script (though I don't know VBA at all, so it wouldn't so easy for me to do).  I'm certain I could do this in other languages.  But then that won't really help, as I'm trying to do this entirely in excel.

I've done it very inelegantly using a formula on another sheet copied down (A1 takes the percentage off the original value, A2 takes the percentage from the value of A1 etc.), and I can then just see which row number the value hits 0, but I was just curious to know if there was a more efficient solution;
a) without using VBA
b) using VBA to do so properly (not important, but I'd like to see how its done if anyone can)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution would be directly calculate the answer directly.

You are looking for something that gets to 0 rounded to 2 decimals so **<0.0049** your formula then becomes

0.0049 = A4 *(1-A1)^n

ln(0.0049) = ln(A4)+ n*ln(1-A1)

n = (ln(0.0049)-ln(a4))/ln(1-A1)

Since you want a whole number of loops you would take the next number higher so final equation is

```
=ceiling((ln(0.0049)-ln(a4))/ln(1-A1),1)
```

(1-A1) refers to how much is left after once iteration.

You said A1 is a percentage.  If you put in 20% in excel it is treated as 0.2.

The original formula should be

0.0049 = A4*(0.8)^n

Comment: I was typing something similar to show that this can indeed be done with a formula, +1

Comment: I think I get the first part (though 0 rounded to 2 decimals would be <=0.0049 I think)... But can you explain the (1-A1)^n from the first formula?? I get ^n is the number of loops, but why 1-A1?? In my example above, then this formula would become 23 * -19 ^n which I just can't get my head around...

Comment: added comments above

Comment: Thanks for the edit... see where I was going wrong now... it was a percentage, but was only stated as a number (the cell value was'20', not 20%' so my I ended up with ln(-19), which is invalid.  I've added the '%' now and I'm all good... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses some kind of "linear calculation model" in which a formula in a cell determines the value of the cell based on the value of other cells, using functions and references. Excel maintains a dependency graph and whenever a cell changes value, it recalculates all dependents, recursively (so dependents of dependents get recalculated too).

The only iteration Excel provides in this model is within functions of the formula.

I believe it is possible in Excel to define a user function that you can use in formulas in your cells.Any iterations you need can be performed by this function (in VBA).

<sub>(P.s.: the other iteration Excel provides is in the circular reference, when the dependents of a cell after zero or more steps comes back to the cell as a dependent of itself. Excel will flag this but I believe it is possibe to allow this and instruct Excel how many iterations to perform.)</sub>